# Auto backup and delete a project directory using cronjob

Tags: linux, centos, backup, cron, rsync

I am trying to backup a directory, location: `/mnt/project/` once in 24 hrs, and another directory inside the parent directory, location: `/mnt/project/uploadDocuments/` every 3 hours using cronjob.

Below are the scripts: 
Application backup daily at midnight

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(date '+%d-%b-%Y')
source=/mnt/project/
mkdir /root/Backup/"$var"
dest=/root/Backup/"$var"/
rootdest=/root/Backup/
rsync -atu $source $dest;
```

upload documents backup daily every 3 hours

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(date '+%d-%b-%Y')
source=/mnt/project/uploadDocuments/
dest=/root/Backup/"$var"/uploadDocuments/
rsync -atu $source $dest;
```

The above scripts do a good job for backing up the directory but i am unable to write a auto delete script because the backed up directories store the same timestamp reference below:
[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtgVu.jpg)

As the directories have the same timestamp i am unable to use the following command for auto delete the directories older than say 7 or 10 days:

```
find $rootdest -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime +10 | xargs rm -rf
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh. Just wrote up a whole answer that made things way more convoluted than they should have been. `rsync` is the most likely culprit here.

After you `rsync`, try `touch`ing `$dest`. The `rsync` is likely changing the timestamp to that of `$source`.

As for fixing the ones that are already there, you could adjust `ctime` using `debugfs`, but you'd need to have the drive **unmounted** to do that (not really possible where you have the backup drive in `/root` unless your root directory is mounted separately).

This would likely do the trick:

`debugfs -w -R "set_inode_field /root/Backup/$var ctime $(date +%s)" /dev/sdX`

PS: Convoluted answer was because I didn't see `rsync` in the first place, and thought there was something wonky going on with your system's assignment of `ctime`.

Comment: oh damn, you are right. rsync -atu keeps the $source 's timestamp, but adding a line touch /root/Backup/"$var" will solve my problem. such silly issue. Thank s a lot